# include and run function in php

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to put some code into an external file as a function and and run it on another page.

here is the function

```
function listBoats(){
    //get record set for all boats sort them by their "sort" number
    $queryBoat = "SELECT * FROM `CSINSTOCK` WHERE `id` <> 'mainPage' ORDER BY `sort` LIMIT 0, 1000";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$queryBoat);
    return $result;
```

and here is how I'm including it on my page

```
include("monthly-specials-cs-functions.php");//get functions
listBoats(); //run query to list all the boats in the CSINSTOCK table
```

It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 4):

You should look into variable scope. In your case, the `$con` variable is undefined in the function so you would have to send it as a parameter.

Comment: That was it! I added the $con parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

all what you miss is

```
$con
```

This variable should be passed to this function or be used as a global at the beginning of function

```
global $con
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 
   include("filename.php"); 
you should use 
require_once "filename.php";